# Google Cloud Storage throwing error for multiple large file uploads concurrently

Tags: java, google-cloud-storage

We are trying to upload multiple files i.e. 100 or more than that to Google Cloud Storage, but we get the 
below error randomly.
**Average File Size: 30MB - 40 MB**

```
 08:57:15.488 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-26] INFO  
 demo.storage.GCPStorageComponent - Error writing request body to
 server com.google.cloud.storage.StorageException: Error writing
 request body to server
at com.google.cloud.storage.spi.v1.HttpStorageRpc.translate(HttpStorageRpc.java:189)
     at com.google.cloud.storage.spi.v1.HttpStorageRpc.write(HttpStorageRpc.java:581)
     at com.google.cloud.storage.BlobWriteChannel$1.run(BlobWriteChannel.java:51)
     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
     at com.google.api.gax.retrying.DirectRetryingExecutor.submit(DirectRetryingExecutor.java:89)
at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.run(RetryHelper.java:74)
at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.runWithRetries(RetryHelper.java:51)
at com.google.cloud.storage.BlobWriteChannel.flushBuffer(BlobWriteChannel.java:47)
     at com.google.cloud.BaseWriteChannel.close(BaseWriteChannel.java:160)
     at demo.storage.GCPStorageComponent.uploadFile(GCPStorageComponent.java:56)
     at demo.storage.StorageRepository.uploadFile(StorageRepository.java:56)
     at demo.restful.UploadRepository.uploadFileToBucket(UploadRepository.java:132)
     at demo.restful.UploadRepository.processClipResults(UploadRepository.java:56)
     at demo.restful.UploadRepository.lambda$getClipModelCallableList$0(UploadRepository.java:85)
     at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1424)
     at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
     at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
     at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
     at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
 Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error writing request body to server
     at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$StreamingOutputStream.checkError(HttpURLConnection.java:3536)
     at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$StreamingOutputStream.write(HttpURLConnection.java:3519)
     at com.google.api.client.util.ByteStreams.copy(ByteStreams.java:55)
     at com.google.api.client.util.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:94)
     at com.google.api.client.http.AbstractInputStreamContent.writeTo(AbstractInputStreamContent.java:72)
     at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:80)
     at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:981)
     at com.google.cloud.storage.spi.v1.HttpStorageRpc.write(HttpStorageRpc.java:563)
     ... 17 more
```

Below is our code, which we are using to upload files. **We are uploading files in chunk of 1 MB using multi-part approach.**

```
public void uploadFile(String bucketName, String bucketFileName, Path localFilePath)
        throws IOException, StorageException {
    BlobInfo blobInfo = BlobInfo.newBuilder(bucketName, bucketFileName).build();
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(10_000_000); //i.e. 1 MB
    try (WriteChannel writer = storage.writer(blobInfo);
            ByteChannel inChannel = Files.newByteChannel(localFilePath);) { // write to bucket
        while (inChannel.read(buffer) > 0) {
            buffer.flip();
            writer.write(buffer);
            buffer.clear();
        }
    } catch (com.google.cloud.storage.StorageException ex) {
        LOGGER.info(ex.getMessage());
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Edit:** Access is being done from within Google Cloud
 An [Github Issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/issues/3410) has been opened for same

Comment: Try [Truncated Exponential Backoff](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/exponential-backoff). See the [example implementation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/transfer/create-client#retry) in Java. Let me know if this is useful to you. Also look at this advice in [parallel uploads](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/generations-preconditions#_ParallelUpload)

Comment: We have the same problem. It happens regularly, but not always. I had a look at the Cloud Storage Java library and it looks like that Truncated Exponential Backoff is already implemented in there, so there's no need to do it on your own. For me it looks like that the Cloud Storage Java library does not retry an IOException and it's super hard to impossible to do it on your own because the Library just exposes a stream / channel where you write to and the library itself flushes single chunks at arbitrary points.

Any updates on your problem ?

Comment: I've additionally added this issue: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/issues/3410

Comment: @nitishkumar-singh Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: nope, issue was occurring more when there was more load on storage API's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Closing this issue as a Bug fix is done for this error and has merged into the latest version of [google cloud java](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java).

Here is the commit link https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/pull/3433

Link for source code changes https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/pull/3433/commits/8e20b1c41e1ae99c4761f716c1ab4dc0f9fbf5e0